# Is there a way to get the URI on which page a flow action has been triggered?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

Currently I am using a custom action which is being triggered on Newsletter/Sign-up.

Since we have multiple Occasions on registering for the Newsletter like account Registration, Checkout Registering and after login within customer edit I would like to know which way the Recipient chose for registering up.

FYI: We still use 6.4.x since we can not update currently and used this documentation for creating the action: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-action

Neither inside the `$event` of FlowEvent or its context I can find any Information about any kind of referrer. Is there any Shopware native way in order to receive the referrer like '/account/login' or '/checkout/register'?

I already have a solution using the $_SERVER['HTTP-REFERER'] but since this way is not exactly secure and has GDPR concerns I would like to find a different approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to `SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent` with a subscriber and add the path info from the current request stack as an extension to the instance of `Context`. In your implementation of `FlowAction` you can then get the instance of `Context` and subsequently the added extension with the path.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Subscriber\SalesChannelContextResolvedSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\SalesChannel\Struct\TextStruct;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Event\SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SalesChannelContextResolvedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private RequestStack $requestStack;
    
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) 
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent::class => 'onSalesChannelContextResolved',
        ];
    }

    public function onSalesChannelContextCreated(SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent $event): void
    {
        $context = $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getContext();
        $request = $this->requestStack->getMainRequest();
        
        if (!$request) {
            return;
        }
        
        $context->addExtension(
            'currentRequestPath',
            new TextStruct($request->getPathInfo())
        );
    }
}
```

And then in your `FlowAction` implementation:

```php
public function handle(FlowEvent $event): void
{
    $currentRequestPathExtension = $event->getContext()->getExtension('currentRequestPath');
    $pathInfo = null;

    if ($currentRequestPathExtension instanceof TextStruct) {
        $pathInfo = $currentRequestPathExtension->getContent();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to use this solution to get the pathinfo for the customer registration inside my action!